# web service stop working

Tags: web-services

[image]I have created a few custom SharePoint 2013 lists which using  Ajax to receive few users information (Auto filed, Users name, email, phone number). I have recently start using https by installing the certificates and updating the IIS. however since using HTTPS non of the users information doesn't work and they all return empty. I don't know where to start the trouble shooting.

Error message:

This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

[image]

Kind Regards

Comment: Your AJAX request is updated to HTTPS? Please double check if your content is serving over HTTPS as written in error message.

Comment: For sure you are requesting HTTPS content through a HTTP protocol. Try to update your Ajax request URI with HTTPs.

Comment: This is my code, can you please show me where I can change the url.

Comment: Paste your complete url with hiding tenant name, `XmlToJsonService` paste it's url also.